# How do I get a CSS3 animation to play on scroll down and in reverse on scroll up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a blogger website and I've set up sticky navigation. Ideally, I'd like for the sticky navigation to fit to the width of the browser once activated. I've figured out how to do that, but when I scroll back up, it pops back into place without any animation. I'm trying to figure out how I can put the navigation bar back in its initial place while shrinking back to its original size. You can see what I mean on [my test blog](http://www.finesttest.blogspot.com/). It animates on scroll down, but not on scroll up.

I apologize I can't make a JSFiddle for this because the template I'm using is very complicated. However, I am fairly certain that a Javascript code would do the trick. It would need to be implemented in the already existing code, however, as that code is the one that activates the sticky navigation.

Here's the CSS that is used for the navigation bar once it becomes fixed; and below I've included a `.unfixed` property to reverse the animation. I just need to figure out how to properly activate it in the Javascript code.

```
sticknav {
    background: #b50000;
    height: 46px;
    width: 1080px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 413px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 4px solid #e50000;
    webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
}

.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    animation: fill 333ms forwards ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: fill 333ms forwards ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes fill {
    from {margin-left: 413px; width: 1080px;}
    to {margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fill {
    from {margin-left: 413px; width: 1080px;}
    to {margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
}
.unfixed {
    position:fixed;
    animation: unfill 333ms forwards ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: unfill 333ms ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes unfill {
    from {margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
    to {margin-left: 413px; width: 1080px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes unfill {
    from {margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
    to {margin-left: 413px; width: 1080px;}
}
```

And finally, here's the Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var aboveHeight = 205;

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop()  aboveHeight){
      $('sticknav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
    } else {
      $('sticknav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
    }
  });
});
```

Here's a slightly modified code that works partially. When the page loads and any scrolling is done, the bar gets fixed to the top. However, when I scroll 205 pixels down, it expands. When I scroll back up, it retracts, but it stays fixed. I want it to return to its original position on the board (i.e. no longer be fixed.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var aboveHeight = 205;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
        $('sticknav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
        } else {
       $('sticknav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < aboveHeight){
        $('sticknav').addClass('unfixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
        } else {
       $('sticknav').removeClass('unfixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `transition`?

Comment: I think I tried that but it didnt work. Generally transition is used for hovering over things with your mouse

Comment: You can use `transition` any time you go from one state to another, which is perfect for your situation.  I'd start by replacing all the animation clutter with transitions.  Also, I think the main problem is when you go from `position: relative` to `position: fixed`.  CSS animations/transitions no-likey.

Comment: I'll probably need some help with that but I'll see what I can do. In the end, will it still smoothly transition back to what it's supposed to? Otherwise there would be no point

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sticknav {
    background: #b50000;
    height: 46px;
    width: 1080px;
    margin:auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 4px solid #e50000;
    webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);


    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
       -moz-transition: all 1s;
        -ms-transition: all 1s;
         -o-transition: all 1s;
            transition: all 1s;

}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

---

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 205){
        $('sticknav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
    } else {
        $('sticknav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
    } 
});
```

Comment: I believe what you've done there cancels out each other. Thanks for the attempt, but I'm afraid more Javascript will be needed versus just adding a few lines. I've tried a lot with this code and the closest I've got was where it expands when I scroll past 205 pixels and then retracts with animation when I scroll back up but it stays fixed. Maybe I should add that code to my OP to give a boost to others.

Comment: Okay, that almost works. It does something funky when you scroll down initially and then also it doesn't play the reverse animation.

Comment: @MarkSchauer I tried to make it simpler. The width for the .fixed class is in pixels for the transition to work (at least in some browsers, I think) as the initial width is in pixels. You will need to set the 100% width in px using js/jQuery.

Comment: Once again, almost works! I can probably work with it, you can see what I mean if you visit my test blog in OP. And I'm not sure how I'd set the 100% width in JS.

Comment: Also it doesn't quite transition back correctly, only the right side transitions back and the left snaps back immediately. Could be something to do with the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional condition when the scroll is less than the aboveHeight:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var aboveHeight = 205;
  $('.sticknav').addClass('unfixed');

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight &&  $('.sticknav').hasClass('unfixed')){
      $('.sticknav').addClass('fixed').removeClass('unfixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
    } else if($(window).scrollTop() < aboveHeight  &&  $('.sticknav').hasClass('fixed')){
      $('.sticknav').addClass('unfixed').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
    }
  });
});
```

Also, you might want to move the CSS (top, padding) to the css file.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Of course, it may be Blogger, because it's very picky and won't accept &&, you need &amp; instead. It won't become fixed at all with that code but I appreciate the help!

Comment: And you also are using a <sticknav></sticknav> html label wich is not valid. Is that label part of blogger or something?

Comment: You should change it so it's a class instead. Look, it works: http://jsbin.com/hijaguxive/edit?js,output

Comment: Funny, right? It's linked to the sticknav CSS—and I guess, technically, Blogger uses XML. My bad for not specifying. Still, it's not technically valid but it works.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code in my fiddle. Now it works with the funny "sticknav" label

Comment: Indeed it works but not as intended. It looks pretty much just like the last JS code in my OP. Maybe there's something not right somewhere else because it's not deactivating properly. That is, .unfixed should activate only after .fixed deactivates. Because my nav bar isn't at the top of my screen. Maybe it's just too complicated, but www.gamerebels.com does it just fine.

Comment: This is the foundation to play a css animation on scroll down and reverse it on scroll up, as you asked. Having said so, you might need to edit your css in the unfixed, so it's not fixed anymore and fits where it was before.

Comment: Hmm, it still deactivates immediately without playing the animation in reverse. I think I'll just stick to not using animations or transitions because they're too complicated.